# How does Python evaluate 'and' in a recursive function?

Tags: python

Let's imagine that we want to check if all the elements of a list are positive. We can define a function :

```
def check_positive(array):
    if not array:
        return True
    else:
        if array[0] <= 0:
            return False
        else:
            return check_positive(array[1:])
```

This function is tail-recursive.
Another way to write this function is the following :

```
def check_positive(array):
    if not array:
        return True
    else:
        return (array[0] > 0) and (check_positive(array[1:])
```

Is this function tail-recursive as well?

I guess, what i'm asking is if you ask Python to evaluate :

```
True and (f(x))
```

will it evaluate `f(x)` and then evaluate `True and (whatever is the result of f(x))`, or will it evaluate `True and f(x)` to be equivalent to 'f(x)' and end its evaluation of the expression by evaluating 'f(x)'?

Comment: You could try and see what happens. It's not difficult to design a simple test to discriminate between the two behaviours.

Comment: It evaluates the function and then compares the result to True.

Comment: @MaxPowers, ...it *checks whether it's truthy* (aka whether `bool(x) is True`), which is not the same as a direct comparison to True. The number `10` is truthy, but `10 == True` is false.

Comment: Truthy? Bools are implemented as integer in Python, as far as I know, and that's why `10 == True` is False, but `1 == True` is True.

Comment: "and", "or", "if", and "while" consider things truthy or falsy.  `[]` is falsy, `[1]` is truthy.  `""` is falsy, `"x"` is truthy, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line:

```
return (array[0] > 0) and (check_positive(array[1:]))
```

will evaluate `array[0] > 0`.  If it is false, it will return false without calling `check_positive`.  If it is true, then it will call `check_positive(array[1:])`.  So it has the same evaluation order as your first example.

Note though that tail-recursive is not an interesting characteristic in Python, because Python does not do tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it like this:

```
arr = [0]*10**6
check_positive(arr)
```

This ends instantly, compared with this:

```
arr = [1]*10**6
check_positive(arr)
```

which is very slow.

So you can conclude, that yes, it is tail recursive.

(its a terrible way of doing this in python tho)